# keeping div displayed and hide the old one

Tags: javascript, css

I have a top-navigation list, each one suppose to open a list of links on the side.. these list of links are hidden at first then, it should be displayed (and the previous showed list of links should be hidden) ..
The side links show up perfectly when I hit the corresponding top navigation link, but whenever I click on one of these links, all side links disappear.. solved it by calling function to keep it displayed, but then another problem has showed up.. when I click another top-navigation link (which suppose to open another side list of links) the first one doesn't hide.. and the second one doesn't show up!!
 after long time of searching and trying new stuff, I tried many things.. and yet it doesn't work properly!

my javascript:

```
var prevItem = null;
function hereB(t)
{
   switch (t)
   {
      case 'item-1':
        showIT('left-1');
        break;
      case 'item-2':
        showIT('left-2');
        break;
   } 
   if(prevItem != null)
   {    
      var preI = document.getElementById(t); 
      prevItem.className += "box";
      prevItem.className = prevItem.className.replace(/{\b}?hereB/, "");  
   }
   t.className += " hereB";
   prevItem = t; 
}

function inform(t){alert(document.getElementById(t))}

function showIT(d)
{         
    switch(d)
    {
      case 'left-1':                                            
        document.getElementById('left-2').style.display="none"; 
        document.getElementById('left-2').style.visibility="hidden";

        document.getElementById(d).style.display="block"; 
        document.getElementById(d).style.visibility="visible";        
        break;
      case 'left-2':
        document.getElementById('left-1').style.display="none"; 
        document.getElementById('left-1').style.visibility="hidden";

        document.getElementById(d).style.display="block"; 
        document.getElementById(d).style.visibility="visible";
        break;   
    }
}
```

here's the whole thing at jsFiddle:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ZPbNE/4/

any suggestions will be highly appreciated..

******** *UPDATE The complete answer* **********
the whole java script code to get everything working fine and properly is like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var prevItem = null;
function hereB(t)
{      

   showIT(t.hash.substr(1));
   if(prevItem != null)
   {    
      prevItem.className += "box";
      prevItem.className = prevItem.className.replace(/{\b}?activeTOP/, "");  
   }
   t.className += " activeTOP";
   prevItem = t; 
}

function showIT(d)
{    

    switch(d)
    {
      case 'left-1':                                            
        document.getElementById('left-2').style.display="none"; 
        document.getElementById('left-2').style.visibility="hidden";

        document.getElementById(d).style.display="block"; 
        document.getElementById(d).style.visibility="visible"; 
        break;
      case 'left-2':
        document.getElementById('left-1').style.display="none"; 
        document.getElementById('left-1').style.visibility="hidden";

        document.getElementById(d).style.display="block"; 
        document.getElementById(d).style.visibility="visible";
        break;  
      default:
        document.getElementById('left-1').style.display="none"; 
        document.getElementById('left-1').style.visibility="hidden";  
        document.getElementById('left-2').style.display="none"; 
        document.getElementById('left-2').style.visibility="hidden";
        break;
    }      
}
</script>
```

in the html call it like:

```
<a href="#item-4"  onClick="hereB(this)"> GO item-5 </a>
```

Comment: What are you supposed to be matching with the `switch` statement in `hereB()`? `t` is `this`, which is the anchor element, not a string. Your cases don't match the `href` value, the only thing they match is the ID of the parent `LI`.

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOOOO MUCH .. I just replaced 'code'this to tha name of the div and it magically worked:)) would you please respond to my Q as an answer so I check it Answered? thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
function hereB(t) {
    showIT(t.hash.substr(1));
    if (prevItem != null) {
        prevItem.className += "box";
        prevItem.className = prevItem.className.replace(/{\b}?hereB/, "");
    }
    t.className += " hereB";
    prevItem = t;
}
```

I removed the `switch` statement, and just used the ID in the hash of the href. I also removed the assignment of `preI`; it was giving a node rather than a string to `getElementById`, and it wasn't being used anyway.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ZPbNE/16/)

Comment: thank you for answering.. the comment on my question has answered correctly.. I'm new to js, so I really don't know what "hash" is for.. I'll search for it and get more tutorial on js.. thank you again for your respose

Comment: hash is the part of the URL in href beginning with `#`.

Comment: thank you for explaining.. what I mean I don't know what is the whole statement is for.. may I ask another related Q? after changing hereB(this) to hereB('item-1'), the effects of the active link has gone.. so I replaced "t" into document.getelementbyid(t) at js code, and yet the css-effecs that worked before are not working anymore..do you have any idea? thank you

Comment: The whole statement is so that it will show the element whose ID matches the `href="#xxx"` attribute of the anchor you clicked on. That way you don't have to put the string in the `hereB()` call, it will figure it out automatically. I'm not sure what's going wrong with your new code, since I can't see it. If you change one thing, you have to change other things to match -- you have to be careful about which bits expect `t` to be an ID versus the whole element.

Comment: oh.. now I got it..  it's really usefull and I already replaced it.. thank you for the explaination.. about the new problem i'm working on it right now.. hope it'll be solved tonight.. thank you again..